# Can't find AppPermissons in app manifest (Azure Active directory)

Tags: azure, permissions, active-directory

As of yesterday I added a webapi and a native app to my Azure AD. 
Yesterday I was able to download the WEBAPI's manifest file to add appPermissions (for delegating permissions to the native app).

Not there's no longer any appPermissions located in the manifest file, it has changed. I have tried to add new apps, and even a new AD.

Now theres only appRoles there.

Does anyone know why this is, and how I could solve this so i still can delegate permissions?

---

Might this be the new thing to use?

```
oauth2Permissions": [
    {
        "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application full access to the service on behalf of the signed-in user",
        "adminConsentDisplayName": "Have full access to the service",
        "id": "23906603-82b7-4471-afbd-b6bcf2fe7b1a",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "origin": "Application",
        "type": "User",
        "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application full access to the service on your behalf",
        "userConsentDisplayName": "Have full access to the service",
        "value": "user_impersonation"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 2):

@Simon Agren is right, and that new oauth2Permissions worked for me. Just download an old existing Maninifest and you will see how it now uses the oauth2Permissions instead of the appPermissions. Remember to create a new GUID for the id attribute.
I also turned surprised when I saw that this morning :)

Cheers.